# Error: Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

This piece of code keep making this error. :

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Repository.DBModel.Subscriber'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I've Changed it a few times but it keeps coming up with this Error.

```
using (SubscriberDBHandler db = new SubscriberDBHandler())
{
    IEnumerable <Subscriber> NewSubscribers = Subscribers
                                              .Where(sub => db.Subscriber
                                              .Any(aSub => !aSub.Email.Equals(sub.Email)));
    List<Subscriber> updateSubscribers = db.Subscriber
                                           .Where(dbSub => Subscribers
                                           .Any(lSub => lSub.Email
                                           .Equals(dbSub.Email))).ToList();
    if(NewSubscribers.Count() >= 1)
    {
        db.Subscriber.AddRange(NewSubscribers);
    }
    updateSubscribers.ForEach(aSub => aSub.State = Subscribers
                                                  .FirstOrDefault(sub => sub.Email
                                                  .Equals(aSub.Email)).State ?? "Error" );
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could point out my error or come up with a more efficient way to do this.

In advance thanks for your time and help.

---

I know there are a few post with this error out there but when reading them I can't figure out how they relate to my problem. so I'm sorry if this is a common mistake and others have provided a solution

The object Subscribers is a `List<Subscriber>`

I don't seem to be able to find the line but. the stack trace does contain this.

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Repository.SubScribRepository.AddOrUpdateSubscribers(List`1 Subscribers)

Comment: Hi, please put a little effort into formatting your code (proper indenting, etc), removing commented out code and letting us know on which line the error occurs.

Comment: what type is this object "Subscribers" ? or please post the entity model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a local collection, `Subscribers`, directly in a LINQ statement. But these objects can't be translated into SQL. There are only mappings from primitive types to database types.

I'd suggest you use

```
var emails = Subscribers.Select(s => s.Email).ToList();
```

And proceed by using these strings (i.e. primitive values) in `Contains` statements like:

```
var newSubscribers = db.Subscriber
                       .Where(dbSub => !emails.Contains(dbSub.Email))
                       .ToList();
var updateSubscribers = db.Subscriber
                          .Where(dbSub => emails.Contains(dbSub.Email))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: I see I will change to this and see if my problem persist.

just to be clear. 

my mistake was that the List<Subscriber>  Subscribers
can't be used inside a LINQ statement because the translation to primitive types won't work. Even thou the Subscriber object is created from a DB representation class.?

Comment: Yes, that's because entity objects, like `Subscribers`, can only be used in LINQ when they are part of the LINQ Expression, like `context.Subscribers`. When they're in local memory, there's no way to create SQL from them. Like `context.Subscribers.Where(s => s == localSubscriberObject)` - hard to turn that into SQL.

Comment: Probably too many email addresses? Try to get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24534217/861716) scalable contains method working.

Comment: I'd say we got about 70000 rows with emails so yea I think this could be a problem after reading the link you provided Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing updateSubscribers to an IEnumerable will prevent this error