# Linq with number of queries to the same table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

Recently I have a small headache with Linq. 
I have one big table(more than 100 fields and for the test purpose more than 40000 rows), lets call it Products.

There is about 60 queries to Products table - that I have to show on Grid - queries are IQueryable objects, and I'm doing Count() on every of them.

Every query takes about 100ms(about 7s for all of them), so it takes lots of time to show the result to the user. 
Should I use StoredProcedure, or is there any other solution to this issue?

Best regards

EDIT:
One of my query:
var result = (from f in this.Context.Products
              where f.Period == currPeriod && (f.TYPE == 1 || f.TYPE == 2) && f.FLAGA > 0 && f.DATE_OK != null && UsersList.Contains(f.UsersId)
              select new ProductLista
              {});

In select new ProductList I take 10 fields from Products table. 
Also I know that Contains gives me big issue performance

Comment: and can you please share the queries with us?

Comment: How many items does `UsersList` typically contain? By the way, a table with > 100 fields sounds like an unhealthy db design, you probably need some normalization steps.

Comment: Users list is like from 100 to 4000. Is hard to say realy
Unfortunately I dont have any influence on table design:(

Comment: With 100 this shouldn't be a problem. If it is, you have to look at proper indexing. With larger numbers you must get the data in chunks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24534217/861716.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it is better moving to Sp it will be more efficient also you can try only use Count In LINQ Except Select.

Comment: I use count but on IQueryable result object, the reason is that i will use this query when user clicks on this counter result in grid. 
I dont want to have the same query twice in my project, that is way I went this way.

Comment: If you want only get count please avoid select section in query. that will be performance issue. since if you use IQueryable  you can get count without execute Select  statement. you can it later when you need display all data

Comment: So I should make 2 queries one for count one for select? I thought IQueryable is nice to deal with count and select at one time.

Comment: Please use Lambda Expression that will be help you to resolve this issue

var reuslt = Context.Products where(f=> f.Period == currPeriod && (f.TYPE == 1 || f.TYPE == 2) && f.FLAGA > 0 && f.DATE_OK != null && UsersList.Contains(f.UsersId)).count(); 

This is Deffered Query

Comment: no need 2 query just put main selection into IQueyable then you can execute count and Select method separately like below

e var reuslt = Context.Products where(f=> f.Period == currPeriod && (f.TYPE == 1 || f.TYPE == 2) && f.FLAGA > 0 && f.DATE_OK != null && UsersList.Contains(f.UsersId));

if you need count : result.Count();

If you need select : result.select(a=> new ProductLista { name = a.name});

Comment: So, I changed all my queries just like you sad...there's no significant improve. I think I will go with stored procedure. 
The biggest influence on query performance gives UsersList.Contains.  Without it,  there's 40ms inmprove on each query