# EntityFramework - contains query of composite key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

given a list of ids, I can query all relevant rows by:

```
context.Table.Where(q => listOfIds.Contains(q.Id));
```

But how do you achieve the same functionality when the Table has a composite key?

Comment: I like EntityFramework, and I like composite keys, but I don't like them together. EntityFramework was *definitely* built with simple surrogate keys in mind.

Comment: I think this is not the right question because this is not natural to SQL. How would you do it in the later language?

Comment: Anyone landing here: I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819284/861716).

Comment: Worth looking at the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496766/can-i-join-a-table-to-a-list-using-linq) too

Comment: @GertArnold I usually agree with you, but the answer you are recommending instead of your own, while is good (even though I've seen other similar OSS packages), is SqlServer specific and cannot be used generally. So without EF Core integrated support, I still believe your answer is the most complete and generally applicable, and I always am (and will continue) using it as duplicate target for similar questions in EF Core tags.

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, of course it starts off by saying it's SQL Server-specific, but I could have mentioned that. In that context it works pretty good (although, personally, I'm wary of using such packages in production. Again, it's something we'd love EF to support themselves).

Answer (score 88):

This is a nasty problem for which I don't know any elegant solution.

Suppose you have these key combinations, and you only want to select the marked ones (*).

```
Id1  Id2
---  ---
1    2 *
1    3
1    6
2    2 *
2    3 *
... (many more)
```

How to do this is a way that Entity Framework is happy? Let's look at some possible solutions and see if they're any good.

#### Solution 1: `Join` (or `Contains`) with pairs

The best solution would be to create a list of the pairs you want, for instance Tuples, (`List<Tuple<int,int>>`) and join the database data with this list:

```cs
from entity in db.Table // db is a DbContext
join pair in Tuples on new { entity.Id1, entity.Id2 }
                equals new { Id1 = pair.Item1, Id2 = pair.Item2 }
select entity
```

In LINQ to objects this would be perfect, but, too bad, EF will throw an exception like

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Tuple`2 (...) Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

which is a rather clumsy way to tell you that it can't translate this statement into SQL, because `Tuples` is not a list of primitive values (like `int` or `string`). For the same reason a similar statement using `Contains` (or any other LINQ statement) would fail.

#### Solution 2: In-memory

Of course we could turn the problem into simple LINQ to objects like so:

```cs
from entity in db.Table.AsEnumerable() // fetch db.Table into memory first
join pair Tuples on new { entity.Id1, entity.Id2 }
             equals new { Id1 = pair.Item1, Id2 = pair.Item2 }
select entity
```

Needless to say that this is not a good solution. `db.Table` could contain millions of records.

#### Solution 3: Two `Contains` statements (incorrect)

So let's offer EF two lists of primitive values, `[1,2]` for `Id1` and `[2,3]` for `Id2`. We don't want to use join, so let's use `Contains`:

```cs
from entity in db.Table
where ids1.Contains(entity.Id1) && ids2.Contains(entity.Id2)
select entity
```

But now the results also contains entity `{1,3}`! Well, of course, this entity perfectly matches the two predicates. But let's keep in mind that we're getting closer. In stead of pulling millions of entities into memory, we now only get four of them.

#### Solution 4: One `Contains` with computed values

Solution 3 failed because the two separate `Contains` statements don't only filter the *combinations* of their values. What if we create a list of combinations first and try to match these combinations? We know from solution 1 that this list should contain primitive values. For instance:

```
var computed = ids1.Zip(ids2, (i1,i2) => i1 * i2); // [2,6]
```

and the LINQ statement:

```cs
from entity in db.Table
where computed.Contains(entity.Id1 * entity.Id2)
select entity
```

There are some problems with this approach. First, you'll see that this also returns entity `{1,6}`. The combination function (a*b) does not produce values that uniquely identify a pair in the database. Now we could create a list of strings like `["Id1=1,Id2=2","Id1=2,Id2=3]"` and do

```cs
from entity in db.Table
where computed.Contains("Id1=" + entity.Id1 + "," + "Id2=" + entity.Id2)
select entity
```

(This would work in EF6, not in earlier versions).

This is getting pretty messy. But a more important problem is that this solution is not [**sargable**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/861716), which means: it bypasses any database indexes on `Id1` and `Id2` that could have been used otherwise. This will perform very very poorly.

#### Solution 5: Best of 2 and 3

So the most viable solution I can think of is a combination of `Contains` and a `join` in memory: First do the contains statement as in solution 3. Remember, it got us very close to what we wanted. Then refine the query result by joining the result as an in-memory list:

```cs
var rawSelection = from entity in db.Table
                   where ids1.Contains(entity.Id1) && ids2.Contains(entity.Id2)
                   select entity;

var refined = from entity in rawSelection.AsEnumerable()
              join pair in Tuples on new { entity.Id1, entity.Id2 }
                              equals new { Id1 = pair.Item1, Id2 = pair.Item2 }
              select entity;
```

It's not elegant, messy all the same maybe, but so far it's the only scalable<sup>1</sup> solution to this problem I found, and applied in my own code.

#### Solution 6: Build a query with OR clauses

Using a Predicate builder like Linqkit or alternatives, you can build a query that contains an OR clause for each element in the list of combinations. This could be a viable option for *really short* lists. With a couple of hundreds of elements, the query will start performing very poorly. So I don't consider this a good solution unless you can be 100% sure that there will always be a small number of elements. One elaboration of this option can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39310296/861716).

#### Solution 7: Unions

There's also a solution using UNIONs that I [posted later here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585194/861716).

---

<sup>1</sup>As far as the `Contains` statement is scalable: [Scalable Contains method for LINQ against a SQL backend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24534217/861716)

Comment: This (Solution 5) is what I eventually did, but this feels like an awful way to do it...

Comment: It is. The root of the problem is that we have to deal with a desperately outdated language specification (SQL) that never provided a way to join ad hoc multidimensional list in one statement (as we can do with a simple list by the `IN` statement). There are RDBMS-specific work-arounds or fixes (Oracle has a really good one), but EF will probably not invest in implementing these.

Comment: Just to be clear, .Contains will throw an exception if the collection you are running it on exceedes 2100 elements ([here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/6160)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this really insightful answer.

Comment: It's funny you mention Solution 3 because that was the only solution I could think of. Glad I came here and found Solution 3 and 5. Thanks so much for taking the time to write all of this.

Comment: Do you think using a stored procedure with ef core in this situation is better?
@GertArnold

Comment: Let's say it's an alternative. "Better" supposes a comparison that I can't make for everyone.

Answer (score 10):

### Solution for Entity Framework Core with SQL Server

> **NEW!** [QueryableValues `EF6 Edition` has arrived!](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues.EF6)

The following solution makes use of [QueryableValues](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazarTech.QueryableValues.SqlServer/). This is a library that I wrote to primarily solve the problem of [query plan cache pollution in SQL Server](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#the-problem-) caused by queries that compose local values using the `Contains` LINQ method. It also allows you to compose values of [complex types](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#complex-type-example) in your queries in a performant way, which will achieve what's being asked in this question.

First you will need to [install and set up the library](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#getting-started), after doing that you can use any of the following patterns that will allow you to query your entities using a composite key:

```cs
// Required to make the AsQueryableValues method available on the DbContext.
using BlazarTech.QueryableValues;

// Local data that will be used to query by the composite key
// of the fictitious OrderProduct table.
var values = new[]
{
    new { OrderId = 1, ProductId = 10 },
    new { OrderId = 2, ProductId = 20 },
    new { OrderId = 3, ProductId = 30 }
};

// Optional helper variable (needed by the second example due to CS0854)
var queryableValues = dbContext.AsQueryableValues(values);

// Example 1 - Using a Join (preferred).
var example1Results = dbContext
    .OrderProduct
    .Join(
        queryableValues,
        e => new { e.OrderId, e.ProductId },
        v => new { v.OrderId, v.ProductId },
        (e, v) => e
    )
    .ToList();

// Example 2 - Using Any (similar behavior as Contains).
var example2Results = dbContext
    .OrderProduct
    .Where(e => queryableValues
        .Where(v =>
            v.OrderId == e.OrderId &&
            v.ProductId == e.ProductId
        )
        .Any()
    )
    .ToList();
```

#### Useful Links

- [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazarTech.QueryableValues.SqlServer/)
- [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#queryablevalues-)
- [Benchmarks](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#benchmarks)

[QueryableValues](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazarTech.QueryableValues.SqlServer/) is distributed under the MIT license.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to this problem. @sternr, if you're still around please mark it as accepted to make it easier to find.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic and very elegant library!  I do have one question.  The home-grown solution I have been using is a little more cumbersome, but it allows my queries to benefit from index seeks.  I read through the GitHub and Nuget page for your library, but I was unable to determine whether your solution also makes use of something like indexing.  Does it?  I will wind up using it either way, but I think there are some scenarios where your library's elegance and simplicity would not be enough to justify missing out on the index seek.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. I'm glad it's helpful. `QueryableValues` was designed with performance from the ground up, so yes, the generated queries will benefit from any indexes available to cover your query. Just avoid doing any in-fly conversions that will kill the use of your indexes and you will be fine. When dealing with strings (e.g. `varchar`, `nvachar`) pay close attention to the provided documentation of the relevant `AsQueryableValues` method. To be certain, I recommend you to run a profile session, capture the generated query, and then run it in SSMS showing the execution plan so you can confirm.

Comment: @yv989c you comment using the join syntax is preferred, but i find the where any syntax to express the intent more obviously.  Is there a performance benefit to the join syntax that makes you denote it as preferred?

Comment: @ChrisDaMour the SQL generated by each one is different. The LINQ `Join` method will emit a trivial SQL `JOIN` whereas the combo `Where` and `Any` will emit more complex SQL, typically relying on the `EXISTS` operator that won't necessarily have the same performance as a trivial SQL `JOIN`. At the end of the day, SQL server's query engine is the responsible for optimizing your query's execution plan and in my experience the simple the SQL the better it does its duty.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Union` for each composite primary key:

```
var compositeKeys = new List<CK> 
{
    new CK { id1 = 1, id2 = 2 },
    new CK { id1 = 1, id2 = 3 },
    new CK { id1 = 2, id2 = 4 }
};

IQuerable<CK> query = null;
foreach(var ck in compositeKeys)
{
    var temp = context.Table.Where(x => x.id1 == ck.id1 && x.id2 == ck.id2);
    query = query == null ? temp : query.Union(temp);
}
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: May I asked, what is the weakness of this method? It seems to me, it is a good solution and should be the accepted answer. Can anyone see a drawback on this answer?

Comment: @Sam it wil build seperate sql query for each of compositeKeys, then union results - this is the weakes point of this method -performance

Comment: @H.Wojtowicz, it will no be separate sql query for each compositeKeys, it will be **one** query, which consists of several subqueries.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I was imprecise. I meant union take place on sql server side. I meant query is unecessary long as all required conditions can be placed in one sql where - see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19070#issuecomment-562355942)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a collection of strings with both keys like this (I am assuming that your keys are int type):

```
var id1id2Strings = listOfIds.Select(p => p.Id1+ "-" + p.Id2);
```

Then you can just use "Contains" on your db:

```
using (dbEntities context = new dbEntities())
            {
                var rec = await context.Table1.Where(entity => id1id2Strings .Contains(entity.Id1+ "-" + entity.Id2));
                return rec.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: As Gert Arnord has mentioned in his comment "this solution is not sargable, which means: it bypasses any database indexes on Id1 and Id2 that could have been used otherwise. "

Answer (score 1):

You need a set of objects representing the keys you want to query.

```
class Key
{
    int Id1 {get;set;}
    int Id2 {get;set;}
```

If you have two lists and you simply check that each value appears in their respective list then you are getting the cartesian product of the lists - which is likely not what you want. Instead you need to query the specific combinations required

```
List<Key> keys = // get keys;

context.Table.Where(q => keys.Any(k => k.Id1 == q.Id1 && k.Id2 == q.Id2));
```

I'm not completely sure that this is valid use of Entity Framework; you may have issues with sending the `Key` type to the database. If that happens then you can be creative:

```
var composites = keys.Select(k => p1 * k.Id1 + p2 * k.Id2).ToList();
context.Table.Where(q => composites.Contains(p1 * q.Id1 + p2 * q.Id2));
```

You can create an isomorphic function (prime numbers are good for this), something like a hashcode, which you can use to compare the pair of values. As long as the multiplicative factors are co-prime this pattern will be isomorphic (one-to-one) - i.e. the result of `p1*Id1 + p2*Id2` will uniquely identify the values of `Id1` and `Id2` as long as the prime numbers are correctly chosen.

But then you end up in a situation where you're implementing complex concepts and someone is going to have to support this. Probably better to write a stored procedure which takes the valid key objects.

Comment: I'll have to check your first solution, but as for the second - while it would work, it would result in a full table scan instead of using a direct query against the key

Comment: @sternr totally correct. It's very unpleasant. Note my final remark that you're better off writing a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue as well and needed a solution that both did not perform a table scan and also provided exact matches.

This can be achieved by combining Solution 3 and Solution 4 from [Gert Arnold's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26201371/11485514)

```
var firstIds = results.Select(r => r.FirstId);
var secondIds = results.Select(r => r.SecondId);
var compositeIds = results.Select(r => $"{r.FirstId}:{r.SecondId}");
var query = from e in dbContext.Table
 
            //first check the indexes to avoid a table scan
            where firstIds.Contains(e.FirstId) && secondIds.Contains(e.SecondId))
 
            //then compare the compositeId for an exact match
            //ToString() must be called unless using EF Core 5+
            where compositeIds.Contains(e.FirstId.ToString() + ":" + e.SecondId.ToString()))
            select e;
var entities = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

For EF Core I use a slightly modified version of the [bucketized IN method by EricEJ](https://gist.github.com/ErikEJ/6ab62e8b9c226ecacf02a5e5713ff7bd) to map composite keys as tuples. It performs pretty well for small sets of data.

**Sample usage**

```cs
List<(int Id, int Id2)> listOfIds = ...
context.Table.In(listOfIds, q => q.Id, q => q.Id2);
```

**Implementation**

```cs
public static IQueryable<TQuery> In<TKey1, TKey2, TQuery>(
            this IQueryable<TQuery> queryable,
            IEnumerable<(TKey1, TKey2)> values,
            Expression<Func<TQuery, TKey1>> key1Selector,
            Expression<Func<TQuery, TKey2>> key2Selector)
        {
            if (values is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
            }

            if (key1Selector is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key1Selector));
            }

            if (key2Selector is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key2Selector));
            }

            if (!values.Any())
            {
                return queryable.Take(0);
            }

            var distinctValues = Bucketize(values);

            if (distinctValues.Length > 1024)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Too many parameters for SQL Server, reduce the number of parameters", nameof(values));
            }

            var predicates = distinctValues
                .Select(v =>
                {
                    // Create an expression that captures the variable so EF can turn this into a parameterized SQL query
                    Expression<Func<TKey1>> value1AsExpression = () => v.Item1;
                    Expression<Func<TKey2>> value2AsExpression = () => v.Item2;
                    var firstEqual = Expression.Equal(key1Selector.Body, value1AsExpression.Body);

                    var visitor = new ReplaceParameterVisitor(key2Selector.Parameters[0], key1Selector.Parameters[0]);

                    var secondEqual = Expression.Equal(visitor.Visit(key2Selector.Body), value2AsExpression.Body);

                    return Expression.AndAlso(firstEqual, secondEqual);
                })
                .ToList();

            while (predicates.Count > 1)
            {
                predicates = PairWise(predicates).Select(p => Expression.OrElse(p.Item1, p.Item2)).ToList();
            }

            var body = predicates.Single();

            var clause = Expression.Lambda<Func<TQuery, bool>>(body, key1Selector.Parameters[0]);

            return queryable.Where(clause);
        }

        class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private ParameterExpression _oldParameter;
            private ParameterExpression _newParameter;

            public ReplaceParameterVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
            {
                _oldParameter = oldParameter;
                _newParameter = newParameter;
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(node, _oldParameter))
                    return _newParameter;

                return base.VisitParameter(node);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Break a list of items tuples of pairs.
        /// </summary>
        private static IEnumerable<(T, T)> PairWise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
            while (sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var a = sourceEnumerator.Current;
                sourceEnumerator.MoveNext();
                var b = sourceEnumerator.Current;

                yield return (a, b);
            }
        }

        private static TKey[] Bucketize<TKey>(IEnumerable<TKey> values)
        {
            var distinctValueList = values.Distinct().ToList();

            // Calculate bucket size as 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,...
            var bucket = 1;
            while (distinctValueList.Count > bucket)
            {
                bucket *= 2;
            }

            // Fill all slots.
            var lastValue = distinctValueList.Last();
            for (var index = distinctValueList.Count; index < bucket; index++)
            {
                distinctValueList.Add(lastValue);
            }

            var distinctValues = distinctValueList.ToArray();
            return distinctValues;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a general solution, I think there are two things to consider:

1. Avoid multi-column primary keys (will make unit testing easier too).
2. But if you have to, chances are that one of them will reduce the
   query result size to O(n) where n is the size of the ideal query
   result.  From here, its Solution 5 from Gerd Arnold above.

For example, the problem leading me to this question was querying order lines, where the key is order id + order line number + order type, and the source had the order type being implicit.  That is, the order type was a constant, order ID would reduce the query set to order lines of relevant orders, and there would usually be 5 or less of these per order.

To rephrase: If you have a composite key, changes are that one of them have very few duplicates.  Apply Solution 5 from above with that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked with me and the output query was perfect without any parameters

```
using LinqKit; // nuget     
   var customField_Ids = customFields?.Select(t => new CustomFieldKey { Id = t.Id, TicketId = t.TicketId }).ToList();

    var uniqueIds1 = customField_Ids.Select(cf => cf.Id).Distinct().ToList();
    var uniqueIds2 = customField_Ids.Select(cf => cf.TicketId).Distinct().ToList();
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<CustomFieldKey>(false); //LinqKit
    var lambdas = new List<Expression<Func<CustomFieldKey, bool>>>();
    foreach (var cfKey in customField_Ids)
    {
        var id = uniqueIds1.Where(uid => uid == cfKey.Id).Take(1).ToList();
        var ticketId = uniqueIds2.Where(uid => uid == cfKey.TicketId).Take(1).ToList();
        lambdas.Add(t => id.Contains(t.Id) && ticketId.Contains(t.TicketId));
    }

    predicate = AggregateExtensions.AggregateBalanced(lambdas.ToArray(), (expr1, expr2) =>
     {
         var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
         return Expression.Lambda<Func<CustomFieldKey, bool>>
               (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
     });


    var modifiedCustomField_Ids = repository.GetTable<CustomFieldLocal>()
         .Select(cf => new CustomFieldKey() { Id = cf.Id, TicketId = cf.TicketId }).Where(predicate).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a helper for this problem that relies on `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`;

Its a lot of code and don't have time to refactor at the moment but input / suggestions appreciated.

```cs
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIsOneOf<TEntity, TSource>(this IQueryable<TEntity> dbSet, 
            IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TSource,bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
        {
            var (where, pDict) = GetEntityPredicate(predicate, source);
            return dbSet.Where(where, pDict);

            (string WhereStr, IDictionary<string, object> paramDict) GetEntityPredicate(Expression<Func<TEntity, TSource, bool>> func, IEnumerable<TSource> source)
            {
                var firstP = func.Parameters[0];
                var binaryExpressions = RecurseBinaryExpressions((BinaryExpression)func.Body);

                var i = 0;
                var paramDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                var res = new List<string>();
                foreach (var sourceItem in source)
                {
                    var innerRes = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var bExp in binaryExpressions)
                    {
                        var emp = ToEMemberPredicate(firstP, bExp);
                        var val = emp.GetKeyValue(sourceItem);
                        var pName = $"@{i++}";
                        paramDict.Add(pName, val);
                        var str = $"{emp.EntityMemberName} {emp.SQLOperator} {pName}";
                        innerRes.Add(str);
                    }

                    res.Add( "(" + string.Join(" and ", innerRes) + ")");
                }

                var sRes = string.Join(" || ", res);

                return (sRes, paramDict);
            }
            
            EMemberPredicate ToEMemberPredicate(ParameterExpression firstP, BinaryExpression bExp)
            {
                var lMember = (MemberExpression)bExp.Left;
                var rMember = (MemberExpression)bExp.Right;

                var entityMember = lMember.Expression == firstP ? lMember : rMember;
                var keyMember = entityMember == lMember ? rMember : lMember;

                return new EMemberPredicate(entityMember, keyMember, bExp.NodeType);
            }
            List<BinaryExpression> RecurseBinaryExpressions(BinaryExpression e, List<BinaryExpression> runningList = null)
            {
                if (runningList == null) runningList = new List<BinaryExpression>();

                if (e.Left is BinaryExpression lbe)
                {
                    var additions = RecurseBinaryExpressions(lbe);
                    runningList.AddRange(additions);
                }
                
                if (e.Right is BinaryExpression rbe)
                {
                    var additions = RecurseBinaryExpressions(rbe);
                    runningList.AddRange(additions);
                }

                if (e.Left is MemberExpression && e.Right is MemberExpression)
                {
                    runningList.Add(e);
                }

                return runningList;
            }
        }
```

Helper class:

```cs
    public class EMemberPredicate
    {
        public readonly MemberExpression EntityMember;
        public readonly MemberExpression KeyMember;
        public readonly PropertyInfo KeyMemberPropInfo;
        public readonly string EntityMemberName;
        public readonly string SQLOperator;

        public EMemberPredicate(MemberExpression entityMember, MemberExpression keyMember, ExpressionType eType)
        {
            EntityMember = entityMember;
            KeyMember = keyMember;
            KeyMemberPropInfo = (PropertyInfo)keyMember.Member;
            EntityMemberName = entityMember.Member.Name;
            SQLOperator = BinaryExpressionToMSSQLOperator(eType);
        }

        public object GetKeyValue(object o)
        {
            return KeyMemberPropInfo.GetValue(o, null);
        }

        private string BinaryExpressionToMSSQLOperator(ExpressionType eType)
        {
            switch (eType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                    return "==";
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                    return ">";
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return ">=";
                case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                    return "<";
                case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return "<=";
                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                    return "<>";
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{eType} is not a handled Expression Type.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Use Like so:

```cs
// This can be a Tuple or whatever..  If Tuple, then y below would be .Item1, etc.
// This data structure is up to you but is what I use.
[FromBody] List<CustomerAddressPk> cKeys
```

```cs
            var res = await dbCtx.CustomerAddress
                .WhereIsOneOf(cKeys, (x, y) => y.CustomerId == x.CustomerId 
                   && x.AddressId == y.AddressId)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score -1):

in Case of composite key you can use another idlist and add a condition for that in your code

```
context.Table.Where(q => listOfIds.Contains(q.Id) && listOfIds2.Contains(q.Id2));
```

or you can use one another trick create a list of your keys by adding them

```
listofid.add(id+id1+......)
context.Table.Where(q => listOfIds.Contains(q.Id+q.id1+.......));
```

Comment: The first query is wrong (as it assumes uniqueness for both values)  
And the second one would wrong, but would result in a full table scan

Comment: yes i know fist one is wrong but second one i thing it will work give me example of data and result u want  ...

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the second one isn't wrong, but it WILL result in a full table scan which is unacceptable...

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on EF Core 5.0.3 with the Postgres provider.

```
context.Table
    .Select(entity => new
    {
        Entity = entity,
        CompositeKey = entity.Id1 + entity.Id2,
    })
    .Where(x => compositeKeys.Contains(x.CompositeKey))
    .Select(x => x.Entity);
```

This produced SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.Id1 + t.Id2 IN (@__compositeKeys_0)),
```

### Caveats

- this should only be used where the combination of `Id1` and `Id2` will always produce a unique result (e.g., they're both UUIDs)
- this cannot use indexes, though you could save the composite key to the db with an index

Comment: That's a bad idea. Both for numeric and text columns it will generate ambiguous results (both `ab`+`c` and `a`+`bc` produce the same value) *and* scan the entire table without using any indexes

Comment: Good point @PanagiotisKanavos. I was using it where one of the IDs were a UUID so the result was pretty much guaranteed to be unique. I have updated my answer to include this and the index issue caveats.