# Linq exception when join a list on a query result

Tags: c#, sql, linq, exception, join

I have a list:

```
List<MyClass> lstClass1;
```

Where MyClass has 2 simple string property:

```
class MyClass
{
   public string property1 { get; set; }
   public string property2 { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a table on DB, MyTable, to query, where there are two string type columns:

```
MyTable
   column MainKey
   column AlternativeKey
```

For my script, i must select a join of DB and the list, with the following rule: if AlternativeKey exist, select the row if the first 4 characters in AlternativeKey equal to MyClass.property1 or MyClass.Property2, else select the row if the first 4 characters in MainKey equal to MyClass.property1 or MyClass.Property2. This is my implementation:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> source = getMyTable();
List<MyClass> lstClass1 = getListClass();

IQueryable<MyClass> qMyClassList = lstClass1.AsQueryable<MyClass>();

IQueryable<MyTable> selAlternative = from alt in source
                                     join cl1 in qMyClassList on
                                     alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)
                                     equals cl1.property1
                                     join cl2 in qMyClassList on
                                     alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)
                                     equals cl2.property2
                                     where alt.AlternativeKey != null && alt.AlternativeKey.Length >= 4
                                     select alt;

IQueryable<MyTable> selMain = from main in source
                                     join cl1 in qMyClassList on
                                     main.MainKey.Substring(0, 4)
                                     equals cl1.property1
                                     join cl2 in qMyClassList on
                                     main.MainKey.Substring(0, 4)
                                     equals cl2.property2
                                     where main.AlternativeKey == null && main.MainKey.Length >= 4
                                     select main;

source = alt.Union(main);
```

In execution, this query raise this exception when i loop on the result element:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyTable+MyClass'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try not using the equality operator ("==") in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining a **memory** collection: `qMyClassList` to an `IQueryable` datasource. The exception is because the IQueryable LINQ Provider isn't able to translate the `join` into the relevant query.

2 Options, you could consider:

**Option 1:** You could try using `Contains` in the `where` instead of `join`. Your LINQ Query provider may be able to interpret your query as `WHERE .. IN ('val1','val2'...)`. So for you this would look something like this:

```
var selAlternative = from alt in source 
                     where alt.AlternativeKey != null &&
                           property1List.Contains(alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)) &&
                           property2List.Contains(alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)) &&
                     select alt;
```

Remember that `Contains` will only work with primitive types. In your case this seems to be a `string`, so it's fine.

**Option 2**, if you want to keep your join as is, simply `.ToList()` your `source` instance. This usually isn't a good idea if your source is large, since you load the entire dataset into memory and the join is applied in memory.):

```
var selAlternative = from alt in source.ToList()
                     join cl1 in qMyClassList on ...
```

Comment: If that list of `MyClass` is already in memory I suspect the removal of `.AsQueryable<MyClass>()` cleans this right up.  (edit: well, _and_ not declaring it as queryable)

Answer (score 0):

Niels, option 1 is a good suggest, but i must filter like this:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> source = getMyTable();
List<MyClass> lstClass1 = getListClass();

var property1List = (from prp in lstClass1 select prp.property1).Distinct();
var property2List = (from prp in lstClass1 select prp.property2).Distinct();

var selAlternative = from alt in source 
                     where alt.AlternativeKey != null &&
                     (property1List.Contains(alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)) ||
                     property2List.Contains(alt.AlternativeKey.Substring(0, 4)))
                     select alt;

var selMain = from main in source 
                     where main.AlternativeKey == null &&
                     (property1List.Contains(main.MainKey.Substring(0, 4)) ||
                     property2List.Contains(main.MainKey.Substring(0, 4)))
                     select main;

source = alt.Union(main);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note that two `Contains` is [not the same as one join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26201371/861716)!