# LINQ expression that will match multiple bulk inputs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I write a LINQ expression that will match multiple bulk inputs?

This is my database table

```
Members
Division, Department
1           3
4           9       *
5           1
6           3       *
9           2
```

I want to select the members marked with a *

Here are my inputs

```
int[] divisions = new int[2] {4, 6};
int[] department = new int[2] {9, 3};
```

Here's the query I tried

```
var selectedMembers = members.Where(member => divisions.Contains(member.Division) && department.Contains(member.Department)).ToArray();
```

This does not behave correctly in EF. It works when with a single input but not both inputs (Division and Department)
It should return pairs matching in the inputs
eg:

```
Member[] selectedMembers = new Member[2] { new Member{Division=4,Department=9}, new Member{Division=6,Department=3}};
```

Comment: Does `.Zip()` work in Entity Framework?

Comment: you need to query members who belong to any of listed departments and and of listed divisions?

Comment: @Robert yes. is it possible with EF?

Comment: `.Select` is an unfiltered selection that allows you to do a transformation - you need to use `.Where` which is a filtered selection without the transformation (which you don't seem to need).

Comment: that was a typo, it should be .Where

Comment: It is not clear if you want to select matching pairs or if divisions and départements are to be handled independantly. For exemple, if your original data would also contains a line with `6 9` should that line be selected or not?

Comment: This is one of many incarnations of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716). Maybe we should mark it as a duplicate. The answer below by Ivan the expression wizard elaborates on my "option 6" there.

Comment: When you say it does not behave correctly, you should tell us what you get and what you expect as it is not always easy to be sure of both...

Comment: When you update your question in a way to "invalidate" some existing answers, you should make it clear which information has changed as it might affect our vote.

Comment: @GertArnold Looking at the linked question and your answer there, I definitely agree this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of filtering is not supported directly by EF.

One possible solution is to build dynamically a predicate like this:

```
member => (member.Division == divisions[0] && member.Department == departments[0])
       || (member.Division == divisions[1] && member.Department == departments[1])
       ...
       || (member.Division == divisions[N-1] && member.Department == departments[N-1]);
```

Here is how you can do that:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Member), "member");
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Member, bool>>(
    Enumerable.Range(0, divisions.Length)
    .Select(i => new Expression[]
    {
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Division"), Expression.Constant(divisions[i])),
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Department"), Expression.Constant(departments[i])),
    }
    .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso))
    .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse),
    parameter);
var query = members.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: your interpretation of the problem is correct. How efficient is this solution performance wise?

Comment: Good question. I think it should be comparable to `Contains` which translates to SQL `IN (...)`. And will have the same issues if the lists are big. You need to try and see. The problem is that looks like you have no other options, even with raw SQL.

Comment: But thanks to @Gert Arnold, you may take a look at his answer to [EntityFramework - contains query of composite key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198860/entityframework-contains-query-of-composite-key) which provides more complete analysis of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
var member = members.Where(member => divisons.Contains(member.Division) && department.Contains(member.Department)).ToList();
```

You have used `Select` clause, I have modiefied to work with `Where`.

Comment: that was a typo, it should be .Where

Comment: @Jasmine, is it working now?

Comment: What is the difference from OP query (except `ToList` instead of `ToArray`?

Comment: @Phil1970 OP modified question. OP user Select clause in original question

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @Robert 's answer, but will filter the results to make sure the division and department are the same "pair":

```
int[] divisons = { 4, 6 }, departments = { 9, 3 };
var members = new[] { new { Division = 1, Department = 2 } }; // just for testing

var query = members.Where(m => divisons.Contains(m.Division) 
                         && departments.Contains(m.Department));

var member = query.AsEnumerable().Where(m => Array.IndexOf(divisons, m.Division) 
                        == Array.IndexOf(departments, m.Department));
```

Comment: See the discussion between Renan Araújo and me. The same applies to your answer. And more, because you can't use `Enumerable.Range` in an EF LINQ query.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks. Will using `join` or Robert's answer load all members into memory too?

Comment: Well,it's not about loading data into memory, EF (6) doesn't do that automatically. The query just won't run. Robert's answer (Contains) will translate alright into a SQL query with `IN` clauses, but the result isn't correct because it will also return other combinations, like a record Division 4, Department 3 (if present). Two separate joins will display the same flaw.

Comment: @GertArnold, in the comments of his question, OP stated he wants "to query members which belongs to any of listed departments and  listed divisions".

Comment: Well, it's an answer "yes" to a question they probably interpret differently. The problem is in confining the query to specific combinations, otherwise Ivan's answer wouldn't have been accepted.