# Finding many duplicates based on multiple properties in one database hit

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to perform a check on the database to see if the combination of two properties exists in the database check (pre-Unique constraint check for better UX). Doing the check with a single property is easy, no matter how many you're trying to check. I'm unable to find how to do it with multiple properties in an enumerable.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bat { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class FooDupeCheckModel
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bat { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> MatchExists(IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> matches)
{
    return _db.Foos
              .Where(f => matches.Any(m => m.BarId == f.BarId &&
                                           m.BatId == f.BatId))
              .Select(f => new FooDupeCheckModel
              {
                  BarId = f.BarId,
                  BatId = f.BatId
              });
}
```

This unfortunately gives an exception because the complex property `matches` cannot be converted into a SQL script. Only primitive types can be included into a query.

I also tried converting `matches` to a multidimensional array before using it within the query, but indexes are not supported within a query. `.First()` is not allowed to be used their either.

```
public IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> MatchExists(IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> matches)
{
    var matchArray = matches.Select(m => new [] {m.BarId, m.BatId})
                            .ToArray();

    return _db.Foos
              .Where(f => matchArray.Any(m => m[0] == f.BarId &&
                                              m[1] == f.BatId))
              .Select(f => new FooDupeCheckModel
              {
                  BarId = f.BarId,
                  BatId = f.BatId
              });
}
```

This may be one of those situations that is such a niche case, or requires a SQL query that is too complex for Entity Framework that it is not possible. If it *is* possible, then this would be very helpful if someone else runs into the same issue.

I did get around this by looping through and calling the database for each element in `matches`, but if I could do this in one database call, that'd be quicker.

Comment: This is another incarnation of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support comparing tuples. However, you can compare two+ properties by OR-ing together comparisons:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo f
WHERE
(
    (f.Bar = 1 AND f.Bat = 1)
    OR
    (f.Bar = 3 AND f.Bat = 2)
)
```

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to build up an `IQueryable<T>` involving an OR. You can, however, build it up using Expression tree builders:

```
var models = new FooDupeCheckModel[]
{
    new FooDupeCheckModel() { Bar = 1, Bat = 2 },
    new FooDupeCheckModel() { Bar = 1, Bat = 3 }
};
var comparison = getComparison(models);

IQueryable<Foo> foos = new Foo[]
{
    new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 1 },
    new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 2 },
    new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 3 },
    new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 4 }
}.AsQueryable();
var results = foos.Where(comparison).ToArray();

...

private static Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> getComparison(IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> models)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "f");
    var ands = models.Select(m =>
    {
        // Compare Bars
        Expression pBarId = Expression.Property(pe, "Bar");
        Expression vBarId = Expression.Constant(m.Bar);
        Expression bar = Expression.Equal(pBarId, vBarId);

        // Compare Bats
        Expression pBatId = Expression.Property(pe, "Bat");
        Expression vBatId = Expression.Constant(m.Bat);
        Expression bat = Expression.Equal(pBatId, vBatId);

        Expression and = Expression.And(bar, bat);
        return and;
    }).ToArray();
    if (ands.Length == 0)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(Expression.Constant(true), pe);
    }
    else
    {
        Expression ors = ands.First();
        foreach (Expression and in ands.Skip(1))
        {
            ors = Expression.OrElse(ors, and);
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(ors, pe);
    }
}
```

This works against in-memory data structures. Test it again SQL Server; it should generate the corresponding SQL.

Here is a version that supports an arbitrary number of properties with any names:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bat { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooDupeCheckModel
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bat { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var models = new FooDupeCheckModel[]
    {
        new FooDupeCheckModel() { Bar = 1, Bat = 2 },
        new FooDupeCheckModel() { Bar = 1, Bat = 3 }
    };
    var comparison = getComparison<Foo, FooDupeCheckModel>(
        models,
        compare((Foo f) => f.Bar, (FooDupeCheckModel f) => f.Bar),
        compare((Foo f) => f.Bat, (FooDupeCheckModel f) => f.Bat)
    );

    IQueryable<Foo> foos = new Foo[]
    {
        new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 1 },
        new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 2 },
        new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 3 },
        new Foo() { Bar = 1, Bat = 4 }
    }.AsQueryable();
    var query = foos.Where(comparison);
    var results = query.ToArray();
}

private class PropertyComparison
{
    public PropertyInfo FromProperty { get; set; }

    public PropertyInfo ToProperty { get; set; }
}

private static PropertyComparison compare<TFrom, TFromValue, TTo, TToValue>(
    Expression<Func<TFrom, TFromValue>> fromAccessor, 
    Expression<Func<TTo, TToValue>> toAccessor)
{
    MemberExpression fromMemberAccessor = (MemberExpression)fromAccessor.Body;
    PropertyInfo fromProperty = (PropertyInfo)fromMemberAccessor.Member;
    MemberExpression toMemberAccessor = (MemberExpression)toAccessor.Body;
    PropertyInfo toProperty = (PropertyInfo)toMemberAccessor.Member;
    return new PropertyComparison() { FromProperty = fromProperty, ToProperty = toProperty };
}

private static Expression<Func<TFrom, bool>> getComparison<TFrom, TTo>(
    IEnumerable<TTo> models, 
    params PropertyComparison[] comparisons)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFrom), "f");
    if (!models.Any() || !comparisons.Any())
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, bool>>(Expression.Constant(true), pe);
    }
    var ands = models.Select(m =>
    {
        var equals = comparisons.Select(p =>
        {
            PropertyInfo fromProperty = p.FromProperty;
            PropertyInfo toProperty = p.ToProperty;
            object value = toProperty.GetValue(m);

            Expression fromValue = Expression.Property(pe, fromProperty);
            Expression toValue = Expression.Constant(value);
            Expression equal = Expression.Equal(fromValue, toValue);
            return equal;
        }).ToArray();
        var and = equals.First();
        foreach (var equal in equals.Skip(1))
        {
            and = Expression.AndAlso(and, equal);
        }
        return and;
    }).ToArray();
    Expression ors = ands.First();
    foreach (Expression and in ands.Skip(1))
    {
        ors = Expression.OrElse(ors, and);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, bool>>(ors, pe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Foo is a type that belongs to the model, you could project your matches to `IEnumerable<Foo>`, mapping only the two properties of interest, then issue the query. That should make it work.

```
public IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> MatchExists(IEnumerable<FooDupeCheckModel> matches)
{
    //Convert small set to check for dups to objects recognized by the EF
    var fooMatches = matches.Select(m => new Foo() { BarId = m.BardId, BatId = m.BatId });

    //This should now work
    return _db.Foos
              .Where(f => fooMatches.Any(m => m.BarId == f.BarId &&
                                           m.BatId == f.BatId))
              .Select(f => new FooDupeCheckModel
              {
                  BarId = f.BarId,
                  BatId = f.BatId
              });
}
```

Comment: It's a table that would continue to grow throughout the life of the enterprise solution. If it was going to stay a small dataset, I would give that consideration. Thanks!

Comment: @krillgar: The assumption, based on your code, is that the entries you will be checking for duplicates (matches object) will be a relative small set. If that is the case, this solution will work regardless of the size of your data set.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your solution. Could you make some code?

Comment: I just tried implementing this, and am getting the same exception thrown of "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Foo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context." As I saw what you were suggesting, I was thinking that would work too. But, it's an issue because EF doesn't know how to translate the list of complex objects into the SQL query. (I also tried with a .ToList() on `fooMatches`, but got the same exception.) Thanks, though!

Comment: I tried this myself locally and it works. Check your code.