# Linq where closure with model list

Tags: linq

I have a list of this model:
Model1

```
public class Model1//: IConvertible
{
    public int p1 { get; set; }

    public string p2{ get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to do a linq query from another table to get data using a list of **Model1**

```
List<Model1> lList = GetModel();
var test = Model2.Where(p => lList .Any(l => p.p1== l.p1 && p.p2== l.p2)).ToList();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `Model2`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you getting any error or what else?

Comment: `Model2` is a model who contains those properties of Model1, it also has more columns.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan **Unable to create a constant value of type 'Model1'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.** that's the error.

Comment: This is another instance of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716). Somebody did an effort to build a [library](http://tsherlock.tech/2018/03/20/joining-in-memory-list-to-entity-framework-query/) which will join with value tuples, but it was far from mature [last time I tried](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/190364/7251).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concatenated p1 + p2 with Linq

```
   var stringKeys = lList.Select((e, i) => lList[i].p1.ToString() + "_" + lList[i].p2).ToList();
```

Then to use this list in the another query is:

```
   var result = Model2.Where(e => stringKeys.Contains(e.p1 + "_" + e.p2))
                .ToList();
```