# How to search for entities based on collection of composite primary keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0

I have an entity which has composite primary key

```
public class Allocation
{
    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Entity configuration

```
public class AllocationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Allocation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Allocation> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => new { e.WarehouseId, e.ProductId, e.Date }); // Primary key

        builder.Property(e => e.Date).HasColumnType("date");

        builder.HasOne<Warehouse>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.WarehouseId);
        builder.HasOne<Product>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId);
    }
}
```

I can search for one entity by using `Find` method which accepts multiple arguments as primary key

```
var allocation = context.Allocations.Find(warehouseId, productId, date);
```

For entity with one value for primary key  I can search for multiple entities based on collection of primary keys by using `givenkeys.Contains()`

```
var keys = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var entities = context.Products.Where(product => keys.Contains(product.Id)).ToList();
```

How I can search for multiple entities based on multiple composite keys?

```
// Given keys
var keys = new[]
{
    new { WarehouseId = warehouse1.Id, ProductId = product1.Id, Date = 12.January(2020) },
    new { WarehouseId = warehouse1.Id, ProductId = product2.Id, Date = 12.January(2020) },
    new { WarehouseId = warehouse2.Id, ProductId = product1.Id, Date = 13.January(2020) },
    new { WarehouseId = warehouse2.Id, ProductId = product2.Id, Date = 13.January(2020) }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityFramework - contains query of composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198860/entityframework-contains-query-of-composite-key)

Answer (score -1):

```
context.Products.Where(p => keys.Any( k => k.ProductId == p.ProductId 
                                     &&  k.WarehouseId == p.WarehouseId
                                     && k.Date == p.Date
                                     ) 
                       ) 
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Afraid this will not work, because if given keys contains same values as in one of the records, but values located in different keys, this record will be returned, which is not expected behaviour

Comment: yes you are right , I've edited the answer , this should work now as expected

Comment: Please test code before answering. This will throw an exception in EF core 3.

Comment: what is the exception @GertArnold?