# EF Core complex where clause

Tags: sql, ef-core-3.1

EF Core 3.1 throws when running the following query, complaining that it could not generate the right SQL for it.

```cs
var searchPatterns = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

var matches = from entity in _dbContext.Entity
              where searchPatterns.Any(x => entity.Column1.Contains(x))
              select entity;
```

In raw sql, this could translate to something like

```sql
select * from entity
where exists (select x from @SearchPatterns where entity.column1 like '%:' + x + '%'))
```

(where `@SearchPatterns` is a table parameter that holds the records `a`, `b`, and `c`)

How can I rewrite the query to make it possible for EF Core to accept it?

**Edit** The actual query that I am building is much more complicated than the simplified version I presented above. Thus, I am not considering `FromSqlRaw()` as an option that I am willing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raw sql. See: [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

More at: [Executing Raw SQL Queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql)

Other options are described here: [Breaking changes included in EF Core 3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes) - **LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer attempt. In order to present my question more clearly, I stripped away all irrelevant parts from my query. So, in reality, the query is much more complicated. And I am not sure I want to send all of it to EF in raw sql.

Comment: @romar, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092959/efcore-3-1-exists-query-via-any-query-cannot-be-translated).

Comment: Thanks again. Do you confirm that the only two options that I have is to either use client-side evaluation or raw sql?

Comment: AFAIK, yes + `FromSqlInterpolated`, which is mentioned in MSDN documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I will take your word for it, then.

Comment: Good luck! Cheers!