# EF - Use multiple WHERE clause in LINQ method of IEnumerable of objects' properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to fetch a EF model executing the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles 
WHERE (TypeId = 1 AND PlanId = 1) OR (TypeId = 2 AND PlanId = 2) OR (TypeId = 3 AND PlanId = 3);
```

In order to do so, I have the following method:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Vehicle> GetByIds()
{
    IEnumerable<VehicleId> resultIds = new List<VehicleId>()
    {
        new VehicleId(1, 1),
        new VehicleId(2, 2),
        new VehicleId(3, 3)
    };

    var vehicleList = DbSet
        .Where(resultIds.Contains(new VehicleId(s.TypeId, s.PlanId)))
        .ToList();
        
    return vehicleList;
}

// ...
public class VehicleId
{
    public readonly int TypeId;
    public readonly int PlanId;

    public VehicleId(int type, int plan)
    {
        TypeId = type;
        PlanId = plan;
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'VehicleRepository+VehicleId'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I already checked older questions and:

- performing `.Select().Where()` won't fit since I have a huge amount of unfiltered data
- `.Where(s => resultIds.Any(r => r.TypeId == s.TypeId && r.PlanId == s.PlanId))` throws same error

Comment: This _resultIds.Contains(new VehicleId(s.TypeId, s.PlanId))_ because VehicleId does not implement IEquatable<T> ... So by default it will be compare with object.ReferenceEqual, which will always return false, because the instances in resultIds and new VehicleId are different.

Comment: By the way... What type is _ResultId.Parse()_ is returning? How is it implemented? With yield?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly since your code is not clear (what are `ResultId.Parse` and `CreateScanResult`?). But maybe something like this would work: `var resultList = DbSet.Vehicles.Where(vehicle => ids.Contains(vehicle.TypeId) && ids.Contains(vehicle.PlanId)).ToList();`

Comment: @RufusL @LegacyCode Question edited. `ResultId.Parse` returns `List<ResultId>` (not generator). `CreateScanResult()` will only parse DTO from model.

Comment: @RufusL that was a typo, didn't test it, my bad. Question edited

Comment: Please take a moment and look at the code you're presenting. We don't know your classes or methods that aren't shown, so it's a little tough to see where it's going wrong. You posted the `Parse` method, but it doesn't do much more than call `ParseToResultObject`, which we don't see. But more importantly, we don't see what the `ResultId` class looks like, nor `VehicleDto`, nor do we see how a `List<VehicleDto>` can be created from a `List<VehicleId>`. Have you tried the code in my first comment? Does it work?

Comment: @RufusL why do you need to know the method implementation besides its returning type? Isn't it enough? Question is related to `How to apply IEnumerable<T> in multiple WHERE IN clause`, each one per property value. Anyway, your code didn't work due to `The type arguments for method 'bool System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage`

Comment: Note that your SQL query isn't correct. It doesn't filter the exact *combinations* of `TypeId` and `PlanId`, as the LINQ query would. This is a [notorious problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold you are damn right! Thanks for noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "split" resultIds, for example:

```
var resultIds = ResultId.Parse(ids).ToList();
var typeIds = resultIds.Select(vId => vId.TypeId).ToList();
var planIds = resultIds.Select(vId => vId.PlanId).ToList();

var resultList = DbSet
        .Where(s => typeIds.Contains(s.TypeId) && planIds.Contains(s.PlanId)))
        .ToList();
```