# How to filter entities by collection containing two columns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
Id (int, primary key)
UserId (int)
SomeDate (Date)
JsonData (nvarchar)
```

In C# I have a collection resembling the type

```
List<(int UserId, DateTime SomeDate)>
```

How do I find all database entries matching the two fields from my C# collection? I would like to make one database call and not iterate list and search for them one by one.

For example if the C# collection has 2 entries:

```
(1, '2020-01-02'), (5, '2020-01-01')
```

I would like to find any matching database entries. Something like (not real code)

```
context.DatabaseTable
      .Where(e => (e.UserId == 1 && e.SomeDate == '2020-01-02') ||  
            (e.UserId == 5 && e.SomeDate == '2020-01-01') ||
            ... as many conditions as collection has elements...)
```

Comment: `.Where( r => list.Contains((r.UserId, r.SomeDate))`?

Comment: @tymtam Getting the syntax error: "An expression tree may not contain a tuple liternal"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table with `Users`, where every `User` has at least properties `Id` and `SomeDate`. You also have a sequence of combinations of `{UserId, Date}`, and you want to query all `Users` that have a value for {Id, SomeDate} that equals at least one of the values in your collection.

```
List<(int UserId, DateTime SomeDate)> collection = ...

var valuesToCompare = colection.Select(element => new
{
    Id = element.UserId,
    Date = element.SomeDate,
});
var users = dbContext.Users.Where(user => valuesToCompare.Contains(new 
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Date = user.SomeDate,
    }));
```

I'm not really familiar with the new `(int UserId, DateTime SomeDate)` type. If it is possible to convert a User to a new `(int UserId, DateTime SomeDate)`, then you won't have to do the first Select, a Contains will do.

Comment: FYI C#7 introduced the `ValueTuple` types. The syntax you are using is the old Anonymous type syntax.

Comment: Linq Expressions are unable to work with `ValueTuples` because they require method attributes to help with giving "names" to each Tuple value, which Linq Expressions do not support.

Comment: Does not work for me: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<UnsalableRoomsPreventionCache>()
    .Where(u => __valuesToCompare_0.Contains(new { 
        Id = u.Id, 
        Date = u.SomeDate
     }))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."