# How to LINQ filter dbset by list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to filter dbset of entities of such pseudo-structure (field1, field2, field3) using request of IEnumerable of SomeModel where SomeModel contains pairs (field1, field2) (the same fields subset)

I've tried

```
var ordersList3 = await _dbContext.MyEntities.
AsNoTracking().
Where(a => request.Contains(new SomeModel() { field1 = a.field1, field2 = a.field2})).
ToListAsync();
```

but it doesn't work

could you please suggest the correct way of filtering a dbset by list of models containing fields subset?

Comment: `Where(a => request.Any(b => a.field1 == filterField1, a.field2 == filterField2))`

Comment: it asks me to rewrite statement

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'b => EntityShaperExpression: 
    SomeEntity
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.field1 == b.field1' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038

Comment: Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716). This isn't trivial because EF can't translate lists of objects into SQL, like `new SomeModel() { field1 = a.field1, field2 = a.field2}`.

Comment: I would suggest using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to dynamically create `Expression` trees representing the or combination of your tests. I have extension methods that do that for various local code that as a single test is translates to SQL.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: MSSQL and LINQ to entities, EF Core, net 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is nessessary in your case, but sometimes you need to write down the expressions directly. As this can be sort of fun, here you go:

```
public static Expression<Func<PseudoStructure, bool>> GetPredicate<PseudoStructure>(
    IEnumerable<PseudoStructure> request) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PseudoStructure), "o");
    var expression = request.Aggregate(
        (Expression)null,
        (acc, next) => MakeBinary(
            acc, 
            CompareInstances(parameter, next),
            ExpressionType.Or));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<PseudoStructure, bool>>(expression, parameter);
}
```

This method generates an Expression<Func<PseudoStructure, bool>> which consists of Expressions checking equality of instances:

```
private static Expression CompareInstances<PseudoStructure>(
    ParameterExpression parameter,
    PseudoStructure constant) 
        => typeof(PseudoStructure)
        .GetFields()
        .Select(fieldInfo => Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Constant(fieldInfo.GetValue(constant)),
            Expression.Field(parameter, fieldInfo)))
        .Aggregate(
            (Expression)null,
            (expression, binaryExpression) => MakeBinary(expression, binaryExpression, ExpressionType.And)
        );
    }
}
```

Please note that equality means equality of the values of the fields.
MakeBinary is a simple wrapper for Expression.MakeBinary:

```
private static Expression MakeBinary(Expression left, Expression right, ExpressionType expressionType)
    => left == null || right == null ?
        left ?? right
        : Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, left, right);
```

You can use this like so:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int A;
    public decimal B;
    public decimal C;
} 

var values = new List<Foo> {
    new Foo {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3},
    new Foo {A = 4, B = 5, C = 6},
    new Foo {A = 7, B = 8, C = 9},
    new Foo {A = 10, B = 11, C = 12}
};

var expression =
    GetPredicate(new[] { 
        new Foo {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3}, 
        new Foo {A = 10, B = 11, C = 12}
    });

var result = values.AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToList();
```