# use Intersect into IQueryable and EfCore

Tags: entity-framework, iqueryable

I'm trying to use LinQ Intersect (or equivalent) into an IQueryable method but it seems like I'm doing it wrong.

I have some PRODUCTS that match some SPECIFITY (like colors, materials, height...), those specifications have different values, for example:

color : blue, red, yellow
height : 128cm, 152cm...

I need to get the products that match **ALL** the list of couple specifityId / specifityValue I provide.

Here what I'm trying to do:

```
// The list of couple SpecifityID (color, material..) / SpecifityValue (red, yellow, wood...)
List<string> SpecId_SpecValue = new List<string>();

SpecId_SpecValue.Add("3535a444-1139-4a1e-989f-795eb9be43be_BEA");
SpecId_SpecValue.Add("35ad6162-a885-4a6a-8044-78b68f6b2c4b_Purple");

int filterCOunt = SpecId_SpecValue.Count;

var query =
            Products
                    .Include(pd => pd.ProductsSpecifity)
                .Where(z => SpecId_SpecValue
                    .Intersect(z.ProductsSpecifity.Select(x => (x.SpecifityID.ToString() + "_" + x.SpecifityValue)).ToList()).Count() == filterCOunt);
```

I got the error : *InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet() could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.* which mean it can't be translated to SQL and I need to ToList before my filter.

The problem is, I don't want to call ToList() because I got huge number of products in my Database and I don't want to load them in memory before filtering them.

Is there an other way to achieve what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query expresses "products of which all `x.SpecifityID.ToString() + "_" + x.SpecifityValue` combinations exactly match some given combinations".

Set combination operators like `Except` often don't play nice with EF for various reasons I'm not going into here. Fortunately, in many of these cases a work-around can be found by using `Contains`, which EF does support well. In your case:

```cs
var query = Products.Include(pd => pd.ProductsSpecifity)
    .Where(z => z.ProductsSpecifity
        .Select(x => x.SpecifityID.ToString() + "_" + x.SpecifityValue)
            .Count(s => SpecId_SpecValue.Contains(s)) == filterCount);
```

Please note that the comparison is not efficient. Transforming database values before comparison disables any use of indexes (is not *sargable*). But doing this more efficiently isn't trivial in EF, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26198860/861716).

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a solution found in the link @Gert Arnold provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70819284/1143650).

I used [BlazarTech.QueryableValues.SqlServer](https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues#getting-started) @yv989c's answers

Here's what is now working like a charm :

```
// The list of couple SpecifityID (color, material..) / SpecifityValue (red, yellow, wood...)
            Dictionary<Guid, string> SpecId_SpecValue = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

            SpecId_SpecValue.Add(new Guid("3535a444-1139-4a1e-989f-795eb9be43be"), "BEA");
            SpecId_SpecValue.Add(new Guid("35ad6162-a885-4a6a-8044-78b68f6b2c4b"), "Purple");


            // BlazarTech.QueryableValues.SqlServer
            var queryableValues = DbContext.AsQueryableValues(SpecId_SpecValue);

            var query = Products.Include(pd => pd.ProductsSpecifity)
                .Where(x => x.ProductsSpecifity
                    .Where(e => queryableValues
                        .Where(v =>
                            v.Key == e.SpecifityID &&
                            v.Value == e.SpecifityValue
                        )
                        .Any()
                    ).Count() == dynamicFilter.Count);
```