# Obtaining entities from DbSet from a list of matching objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm using `Entity Framework Core 6` and I want to find a series of entities in a `DbSet`. The entities I want to obtain are the ones match some properties in a list of input objects.

I've tried something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> FindEntities(IEnumerable<MyEntityDtos> entries)
{
    return dbContext.MyDbSet.Where(r => entries.Any(e => e.Prop1 == r.Prop1 && e.Prop2 == r.Prop2));            
}
```

But I get the classic EF Core exception saying that my LINQ cannot be translated to a database query (the problem in particular is the `entries.Any(...)` instruction)

I know I can just loop over the list of `entries` and obtain the entities one by one from the DbSet, but that is very slow, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this in EF Core that I don't know about.

Comment: Use this extension [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316). And use in the following way: `dbContext.MyDbSet.FilterByItems(entries, (r, e) => e.Prop1 == r.Prop1 && e.Prop2 == r.Prop2, true);`

Comment: That's weird, I've tried it but as soon as I invoke it the program crashes without even raising an exception, error log tells me: `program exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

Comment: How many entries do you have?

Comment: A lot (tens of thousands). Maybe the expression builder is causing an overflow...

Comment: Well, then I can only suggest third party extension, `FilterByItems` works with small amount of records. What you are trying to do in overall? Upsert?

Comment: Yes, "upsert" is exactly what I'm trying to do, I didn't know this term existed 

Comment: It should be some generic method? How to match records? Via PK? Post sample entity which you are trying to Upsert.

Comment: @Master_T If you want to InsertOrUpdate entities you can this awesome nuget package: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've done this:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetRangeByKey(this DbSet<MyEntity> dbSet, IEnumerable<MyEntity> toFind)
{
    var keys = new HashSet<string>(toFind.Select(e => e.Id));
    IEnumerable<MyEntity> result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i += 1000)
    {
        var keyChunk = keys[i..(Math.Min(i + 1000, keys.Length))];
        var res = dbSet.Where(x => keyChunk.Any(k => x.ResourceArn == k));
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = res;
        }
        else
        {
            result = result.Concat(res);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Basically I get the keys to find in a `HashSet` and use it to perform a `Where` query, which will be translated to a `SQL IN` clause which is quite fast. I do it in chunks because there's a maximum number of values you can put in a `IN` clause before the DB engine refuses it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```cs
public IEnumerable<MyEntity> FindEntities(IEnumerable<MyEntityDtos> entries)
{
    var props1=entries.Select(x=>x.Prop1).ToArray();
    var props2=entries.Select(x=>x.Prop2).ToArray();

    return dbContext.MyDbSet.Where(r => props1.Contains(r.Prop1) && props2.Contains(r.Prop2));            
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, I don't think it does the same thing that I want to do, it would be the same if my function inside `Any` used `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: Yes it would be the same, with EF you can pass only list of values and it will convert it to ``IN`` or ``NOT IN``,

Comment: No it wouldn't. Let's assume the database contains an entity where `Prop1=="X"` and `Prop2=="Y"`. Your expression just checks if one of the `entries` has `Prop1=="X"` and if one has `Prop2=="Y"`, but there are no guarantees at all that they would be the SAME entity.

Comment: @Master_T In case of ``&&`` it works but in ``||`` yes it may lead to unpredictable results

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad This is a pretty hard problem, you will not find any straight forward optimized answer. You can look at this question and answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198860/entityframework-contains-query-of-composite-key