# Left outer join to include null values linq lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, left-join

I have one table in database named Balance and a list of dates as follows:

`List<string> allDates = { "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04" }`

**Balance** table:

```
Id, Amount, BalanceDate
1, 233, "2021-01-02"
2, 442, "2021-01-03
```

I need to fetch the records in Balance table with amount 0 for the missing dates. For example:

```
233, "2021-01-02"
442, "2021-01-03"
0, "2021-01-04"
```

I have tried the following:

```
balnces.GroupJoin(allDates,
       balance => balance.Date,
       d => d,
       (balance, d) => balance);
```

But the records are still the same (only the ones in the balance table)

Comment: any own attempts that you can post? any problem description of what you encountered? is the Balance table in a DataBase?

Comment: the DataBase part is quite important because you [cannot simply join a table with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503315/5174469)

Comment: @MongZhu I have added my attempt. Balance table is a database table as mentioned above

Comment: Please always mentions which type of data access you're using, for example Entity Framework + which version. Use tags to indicate this. That said, GroupJoin is equivalent to *left* outer join. The left part here is balances. If you want to see all dates, dates should be the left part.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

Balance query had been materialized and data are returned from the database.

**Solution 1: With [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-6.0)**

```cs
using System.Linq;

var result = (from a in allDates
            join b in balances on a equals b.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") into ab
            from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Date = a, Amount = b != null ? b.Amount : 0 }
            ).ToList();
```

[Sample Program for Solution 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pO1Rfq)

---

**Solution 2: With `.ToLookup()`**

```cs
var lookup = balances.ToLookup(x => x.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

var result = (from a in allDates
            select new 
            { 
                Date = a, 
                Amount = lookup[a] != null && lookup[a].Count() > 0 ? lookup[a].First().Amount : 0
            }
            ).ToList();
```

[Sample Program for Solution 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31SYgJ)

Answer (score 0):

Given a data structure from database:

```
        private class balance
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public double amount { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
```

You get your data as you want (this is only a mock-up)

```
       List<string> allDates = new List<string> { "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04" };
        List<balance> balances = new List<balance>();
        balances.Add(new balance { id = 1, amount = 233 , date = "2021-01-02" });
        balances.Add(new balance { id = 2, amount = 442, date = "2021-01-03" });
```

you can get your desired result this way:

```
        List<balance> result = allDates.Select(d=> 
            new balance { 
                amount = 
                  balances.Any(s=> s.date == d)?
                         balances.FirstOrDefault(s => s.date == d).amount:0,
                date = d
        }).ToList();
```

If your default contains a 0 in amount instead a null, you can skip the .Any check